# Double rounding query

Tags: c#, double, rounding

Although there are plenty of very similar questions, none of them really fully answered mine so please bear with me.

Given two doubles, I need to round them to two decimal places and then check to see whether the difference is exactly 0.01.

What is the best method to do this?

Comment: You can't represent 0.01 exactly in doubles. Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I just need to do it :)  I am also assuming it is possible.  I was thinking about things such as converting them to decimals or multiplyint the doubles by 100 and round to integers?

Comment: But could you explain *why* do you need to do it? There might be a better way, but it's hard to help you without knowing that.

Comment: Apologies, I don't have the control over the program which outputs these values so that's why.

Comment: How is a program outputting doubles?  Program output is usually text...

Comment: Ok, an API that outputs doubles then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have pointed out the problem of comparing floating point numbers.  Your best bet is to multiply each by 100 and then compare the whole number portions as integers:

```
static bool ExactlyPennyDifference(double d1, double d2)
{
    return Math.Abs((int)Math.Round(d1 * 100) - (int)Math.Round(d2 * 100)) == 1;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this was one of the solutions that I considered.  Isn't it true to say that this doesn't always work though as if I had a double such as 100.0099999999998 then casting to an int would produce 10000 rather than 10001?

Comment: I get 10001 in that example.  The call to Math.Round changes 10000.99999999998 to 10001.0.

Comment: Sorry you are right, don't know how I missed the Math.Round when I looked at it the first time.  When you call Math.Round on a double it returns another double, so isn't it possible that what you think it should round to can't actually be represented by a double and therefore, you can still get an inaccuracy?

Comment: So for example, if 100.01 can't be represented as a double, so is actually stored as something such as 100.0099999999998, if I round to two decimal places then surely it stays as 100.0099999999998 as if it could be stored as 100.01 it would have been in the first place?  Does multiplying by 100 completely negate this risk?

Comment: By wanting to round the number to the nearest hundredth you're saying you don't care about the lower precision.  Yes, 0.10 can't be represented exactly, say it's something like 0.0999999999.  Multiplying that by 100 gives 9.99999999 and which rounded becomes 10.0 which is what you want.

Comment: Yes, multiplying by 100 is the key here.